# How to search entire hard drive for a file?

Tags: files, search

Trying to locate a file, how can I search the entire hard drive for a file?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/714091/my-quest-to-find-the-fastest-search-app-for-linux

Answer (score 218, accepted):

A simple `find / -type f -name ""` would do the trick if you know exact filename.

`find / -type f -iname "filename*"` if you want to match more files (ignore case).

Make sure to properly delimit `\` shell metacharacters in the filename like `*?[]` or replace them with a non-delimited `*`.

Avoid `-type` option if you want to search for directories etc. See manual of find for more information. To see the manual, issue the command:

`man find`

Comment: This will also search all mounted devices as well, might want to just search `/mount/hddyouwanttosearch`

Comment: Worth noting that find is really slow, compared to an indexed search system, such as locate (but also more powerful)

Comment: note that one might wish to add `sudo` ahead of the mentioned command

Answer (score 61):

You could also use `locate` to look for commands. Why do people use *locate* if *find* does the job? Because locate is much faster than find since it just searches through database(s) of indexed locations to find your file/regex.

Examples:

`locate some-file.avi` searches through database(s) of almost every file on the disk for a file called "some-file.avi".

`locate -i "some-file.avi"` will ignore the case of the file you are searching for.

`locate -i "*.txt"` will display a list of locations of all the files with **.txt* extension on your system.

`man locate` for more info on the file.

You might need to run `updatedb` first to ensure the index database is up to date, otherwise, 'locate' might not return what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that `updatedb` must be run as root.

Comment: this is WAY faster than find \ holy cow... thanks!

Comment: If `updatedb` adds `/` to the index by default, how can it still be faster than `find /`?

Answer (score 17):

Start by clicking the "Home Folder" icon in the launcher.

[image]

In the window that opens, click "Search".

[image]

Type what you want to search for in the box, then press enter.
[image]

Under the dropdown for location, choose your hard drive, then click reload.

[image]

The results will then be displayed. Hope that helps!

Comment: The man who asked it states he uses a server, so there is no GUI. But that's a great answer anyway!

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for a string inside a file, you can use grep. Here's a sample command:

```
grep -r -i "some string" /home/yourusername
```

This will find `"some string"` in `/home/yourusername` directory. The search will ignore case (`-i`) and recurse directories (`-r`). You can use `/` as the directory to search in the whole directory but that might not be very efficient.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu, i know that everyone wants to be dogmatic about using command line all the time, and I have in the past been that way, but I love the Gnome "Search for files..." tool.  I think its awesome.

Comment: well i'm on a server

Comment: You should try then the KDE search. It is far better than the gnome one. I am still waiting for Nautilus to catch up with the versatility that the KDE search system has. Dolphin/Konqueror are far better because of it.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about switching to Kubuntu actually.  I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

For a Desktop setup, Install "gnome-search-tool"
`sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool`

**Don't install this in a server, it will also install the ubuntu desktop package.

Thanks to @Rinzwind for pointing that out.**

Filters inlude:

1. Choose the folder you want to search. In this case `\`
2. Contains the text - this is the file name.
3. Date Modified - less or more than in number of days.
4. File size - at least or at most a specified size. You can also search empty files.
5. File owner - user, group or unrecognized owner.
6. Regular expressions - matches regular expressions.
7. You can choose to show hidden files, follow symbolic links or exclude other filesystems.

[image]

Comment: @Rinzwind The question was `Trying to locate a file, how can I search the entire hard drive for a file?` There is no 'server-install' anywhere...

Comment: @Rinzwind Hahah. Nice one. Let me edit my answer and say this is for a desktop setup alone.

Comment: 3

For a Desktop setup, Install "gnome-search-tool"
sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool      
sudo apt install gnome-search-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-search-tool     
  ((((( it's now 2022 ))))))

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remember `find` (which is a very powerful) parameters you could install from official repos:

- **kfind** - file search utility
- **gnome-search-tool** - GNOME tool to search files
- **catfish** - File searching tool which is configurable via the command line

The three of them are great, but I found **kfind** the best.

From [Ubuntu Community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles) you might find useful:

- dpkg -L|--listfiles  ...     List files `owned' by package(s).
- dpkg -S|--search  ...        Find package(s) owning file(s).

Answer (score 1):

If need to find nested in some dirs:

```
find / -type f -wholename "*foo/bar/filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a file or its contents, and you don't want the search to stop if your `ssh` session gets disconnected for some reason, and you want to store the results in a file that you can reference later:

```
$ sudo nohup find / -type f -exec grep -H -i -n mysearchstring '{}' \; -print 2>/dev/null | tee /home/rmoore/find_output.txt &
```