# How to search entire hard drive from a Live USB?

Tags: nautilus

I just installed UBUNTU 13.10 via "Universal USB Installer" on a USB stick.  When I boot into UBUNTU OS/GUI off the USB I can't seem to be able to search for files/folders on my hard drives.

Meaning, when I input any search criteria in as shown here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/91044/248351

I get no results.

I'm pretty sure that's an easy answer, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to mount the hard drives.  In the linked article, see how a couple of drives have "eject" buttons next to them, while others don't?  When you boot from USB, the USB is mounted, but the hard drives may not be mounted.  Click on the drives themselves in the file manager app, which should either show the contents or prompt you to mount them.  Then you should be able to search them, assuming you have appropriate permissions to read things on the drive.