# Need help installing streamlink-twitch-gui on Ubuntu 16.04!

Tags: command-line, 16.04, software-installation, vlc, shortcuts

I am newbie on Linux-Ubuntu OS 16.04 LTS.
Back in Windows, I am watching twitch.tv livestream through VLC player via this [tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/DatGuyLirik/comments/35euxi/ezmode_watch_twitch_trough_vlc_best/)

Now I have a problem installing it on Ubuntu, I have done all of the steps except the last one where I need to make a launcher shortcut & the executable file itself. [This command](https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink-twitch-gui/wiki/Installation#linux-1) won't launch and the terminal says no command for `add-menuitems.sh` nor `start.sh`. I think there is a command before I type those two line.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me from the link you  provided what steps you've been following. Be that as it may, you may find this useful: https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink-twitch-gui/wiki

Comment: I am forgot to include the specific one, here it is. 
[Yup](https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink-twitch-gui/wiki/Installation#linux-1)

Comment: So what part of "After extracting the archive (preferably to /opt), run add-menuitems.sh once for creating menu shortcuts / application icons and run start.sh for launching the application." is confusing you?

Comment: Those isn't confusing me, but the command line says addmenu-items.sh command not found. Even though I have move into /opt/ folder where the extracted files located.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89393/how-to-search-entire-hard-drive-for-a-file

Comment: Sorry sir, I think you misread my line. I am not looking for a files.

Comment: You'll have to find it (and likely add executable permissions) before you can launch it

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
It turns out that the command I need to put is `./`
It turns out to be like this `./addmenu-items.sh` & `./start.sh`

Thank you.