# how to install inspircd on my ubuntu version 17.04 server from the usb drive

Tags: usb, drive

I have installed ubuntu server version 17.04 on a desktop.  I want to install inspircd 2.0.24 on the server and I have it on a thumbdrive..what is the command to tell linux to get it off there and install it?

Comment: Why don't you install it from repository?

Comment: @Arun As of now, v.2.0.24 isn't available in [the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=inspircd&searcho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require version 2.0.24 you can download the deb package from [this link,](https://github.com/inspircd/inspircd/releases/download/v2.0.24/inspircd_2.0.24-1_amd64.deb) and then choose to install it with your favorite package manager. You have a number of options. For example, you can choose to open it with the software center (although you likely don't have a GUI installed on your server), `gdebi` or install it with `dpkg` with `sudo dpkg -i packagename` as indicated by @mariaczi above.

I prefer gdebi for local .deb installation as gdebi lets you install a local deb package resolving and installing its dependencies. apt does the same, but only for remote (http, ftp) located packages.

To use gdebi, (recommended) install it if you don't have it with `sudo apt install gdebi`

**Navigate to the folder containing the package** and then install the desired package with `gdebi inspircd_2.0.24-1_amd64.deb`

`gdebi` will notify you if the package isn't installable due to conflicts or unsatisfiable dependencies which should save you from any unintended consequences.

**If you don't know where to find it**, you can download a fresh copy from the link provided above or use `find` which is explained nicely [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89393/how-to-search-entire-hard-drive-for-a-file)

Comment: got it from a repository, now looking for its directory..any clues what directory inspircd is in on this version?

Comment: Please [edit] pertinent information into your question as comments can be deleted for several reasons. While doing this please include [which repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=inspircd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) (or PPA)  you got version 2.0.24 from.  While you are at it you might explain how it ended up on a thumb drive if you couldn't find it.

Comment: I got it from the Inspircd site, and put it on the same thumbdrive I created to install ubuntu 17.04.  What I meant about not being able to find it is that from the command line of ubuntu I did not know about find, or any of the other things you showed me, and I didn't know the pathname.  You solved all that though, thanks so much.

Comment: noted and done!  but thanks again for getting me out of that frustrated feeling i had.

Comment: @LiahEllerbe Always glad to help! That's what I'm here for. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have it as deb packages you can install it using "dpkg -i /path/to/the/package", but remember to install all required/dependency packages.

Comment: my problem is i don't know how to find the usb drive where the files are located...can you please tell me how to find that?

Comment: @LiahEllerbe see my updated answer.