# Software is installed, but "which" returns "not found"

Tags: software-installation, r

I'm trying to work with the statistical package R. R is already installed. `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` returns:
"r-base-dev is already the newest version (3.4.3-1xenial0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded."
However, `which R` gives me "R not found".

Now, how can I locate R? Is it really installed?

(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/89393/how-to-search-entire-hard-drive-for-a-file

Comment: ...and what do you get from `ls -l /usr/bin/R`?

Comment: `find / -type f -name "R"` returns hundreds of lines, but oddly these two: `/usr/lib/R/bin/R` and `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R`. However, these directories don't exist in the system (I checked in Nautilus) and `ls -l /usr/bin/R` returns "No such file or directory".

Comment: AFAIK `/usr/bin/R` is provided by package `r-base-core`, not `r-base-dev`. The former *should* have been installed as a dependency of the latter - is it possible you removed it at some point?

Comment: Great! I haven't realized that r-base-dev is dependent on r-base-core. There was an r-base also I'm not aware of. I uninstalled everything and reinstalled. Now it's all working. Thanks @steeldriver.  Could you please post your comment as an answer?