# How to I install unetbootin on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, ppa, unetbootin

The following repository `ppa:gezakovacs/ppa`  is not working 
and when I try to install by download method.

```
kmoin@kmoin-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ chmod +x ./unetbootin-linux
chmod: cannot access './unetbootin-linux': No such file or directory
```

Comment: @AmanMittal: If you know the answer please post an actual answer. Comments are meant to ask for clarification from the parent post author. In any case the relative paths `./unetbootin-linux` and `unetbootin-linux` are equivalent. Your recommendation is thus moot.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu), especially [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu/575161#575161)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you appear to be having is blindly following the directions for the binaries provided on the http://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html page without an understanding of the assumptions made.

Essentially the assumption is that you will be executing the command in the directory where you downloaded the file. Assuming the default directory for downloads, your first command should be `cd ~/Downloads` followed by `chmod +x ./unetbootin-linux` and then `./unetbootin-linux`  Personally after making the file executable with `chmod +x ./unetbootin-linux` I would probably want to move it to a directory on my path such as `/bin` or if I didn't want any other users on the system executing it possibly `~/bin` You can examine your path with the command `echo $PATH`

**TL;DR** The upshot is that you need to first know where the file is before you can make it executable. [How to search entire hard drive for a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89393/how-to-search-entire-hard-drive-for-a-file) provides the basic approach to find a file.

**The simple method for 16.04:**

Since 'unetbootin' [is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unetbootin&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) in the Universe repository, all you need to do is [enable it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and then issue the command `sudo apt install unetbootin`

Answer (score 0):

### Try Unetbootin from github

The developer offers **`bin`** versions of Unetbootin for linux via this link,

[unetbootin.github.io/](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

### Try another tool

- The **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator** comes with Ubuntu and there is a robust version in 16.04 LTS and newer versions of Ubuntu.
- **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` is another robust tool that comes with Ubuntu.
- [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works in all current versions of Ubuntu and clones to create a live-only drive for testing and installing Ubuntu. It can also create a persistent live drive, where you can install programs and save data (and they survive shutdown and reboot).