# Create ISO from unetbootin?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb, iso, unetbootin

How can I create an ISO from `unetbootin` to then burn a DVD?

[image: unetbootin]

It looks convenient that the files are already there.  Can they be packaged up as an ISO instead of re-downloading?  (This is from plain vanilla Ubuntu, using `unetbootin`.)

see also:

https://superuser.com/questions/777339/where-does-unetbootin-put-the-downloaded-iso-files

so, maybe the ISO files are there for the taking.  Hmmmm....I will [look](https://askubuntu.com/q/89393/45156):

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ locate -i "*.iso" 
/home/thufir/Desktop/ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso
/home/thufir/Downloads/lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
/home/thufir/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
/home/thufir/Downloads/xenialpup64-7.5-uefi.iso
/usr/lib/memtest86+/memtest86+.iso
thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if I understand correctly, [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io) can *not* burn a DVD, and I don't think it will unpack an iso file. (Maybe Unetbootin stores a temporary copy in the `/tmp` directory, that you could use for that purpose, but it would be better to get and use an iso file the regular way.)

You should use other tools for that purpose:

- [Download an iso file of Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) or an Ubuntu community flavour and [check](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) (for example with md5sum) that it was downloaded correctly.
- Use a burning tool, for example **`k3b`** and 'burn an iso file' with the slowest possible speed. It is a good idea to verify the burning process.

Comment: Yes, the question should be: *where* is that temporary copy?  (Slow internet connection.)

Comment: Yes @Thufir, storing in `/tmp` is a standard way in linux. You could try `sudo find /tmp -name "*.iso*"` -- Locate might not have an update data base, or might skip `/tmp`.

Comment: @Thufir, Fixing typing error: Locate might **not** have an **updated** data base, or might skip `/tmp`.  It is also possible that the iso file is stored under another name, so you should look for files with the correct size. It is also possible, the Unetbootin removes the temporary file at exit. At reboot and shutdown/cold boot, `/tmp` will be cleared, and all files and directories there will be lost.

Comment: I did a few searches, no joy.  Please don't waste more time on this on my account.  Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu 18.04 ISO file can be downloaded from the official [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) webpage or from the terminal using the following command:

```
wget -c http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

The name of the official Ubuntu ISO file is ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso. I prefer using `wget` to download the Ubuntu ISO file because it automatically resumes interrupted downloads from the same place when the download was interrupted, so you never need to download anything twice if there is a temporary glitch in internet connectivity.

Maybe 18.04_Live_x64 is an ISO file already, and you can rename it to 18.04_Live_x64.iso and then burn a DVD. To avoid wasting a DVD, try renaming it to 18.04_Live_x64.iso and then making a bootable Ubuntu 18.04 live USB flash drive using the built-in Startup Disk Creator application. If the Ubuntu 18.04 live USB flash drive boots successfully then it's OK to either burn a DVD from 18.04_Live_x64.iso with the [**Brasero** DVD burner application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307742/how-to-burn-an-ubuntu-iso-image-on-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/828879#828879) or else use the Ubuntu 18.04 live USB flash drive to install Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: yeah, but where *is* the file?  Presumably there's an ISO somewhere...

Comment: @Thufir It's at `http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/` and the ISO is named `ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso`. If you `wget` it, wherever it ends up is wherever you target it to be. Not specifying a target will probably drop it in the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

**UNetbootin** extracts an operating system ISO to USB and provides syslinux as a boot loader.

A program like **Remastersys**, (discontinued), or **ISO respin**, http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/09/new-version-of-iso-respin-script.html or **Pinguy Builder**, https://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/, may be used to put the files back into a bootable ISO.

Alternately you can use **dd** to turn the USB contents into an image file:

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=~/usb2img.img
```

where sdx is the device id of the bootable USB.

The image file can be written to a USB drive using **mkusb** in Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and **Win32 Disk Imager** in Windows, https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/, (or dd in Ubuntu, if desired).

- The new USB will be a duplicate of the original including UUID. GParted can be used to give the partitions unique UUID's if needed.
- If you used UNetbootin's persistence feature, you can add programs, and customize the OS before writing to image, Max 4GB+4GB persistence.
- The latest version of UNetbootin makes a drive bootable with BIOS or UEFI.
- An .img file will compress for transport, (compression speed seems slow).
- You can burn the .img file to CD or DVD using Brasero.

Caution: Do not make any mistakes while using dd, your HDD's may be at risk.