# Where is the Vuze 'executable' located?

Tags: firefox, snap, executable, vuze

I am very new to Ubuntu and I'm struggling. Currently running 16.04 and I've installed Vuze via Ubuntu Software. The manual install was problematic for me.

When I click on a magnet link in Firefox it asks which app I want to open with. Transmission is shown but Vuze isn't listed. I click on 'Choose another Application' but I don't know where the application is. I can see */snap/vuze-vs* with various sub-folders; *3*, *common* and *current* each with their own sub-folders and files, but I have no idea where/what the actual 'executable' is.

Can anyone help? I have Googled extensively but can't find an answer.

Comment: Look at this old thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89393/how-to-search-entire-hard-drive-for-a-file to see if it helps

Comment: Have you looked in `/snap/bin`?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what I'm searching for. In windows I'd look for '*.exe' in the sub-folder.

Comment: If the executable is called `vuze`, you can just `whereis vuze`.  Files are just files, but an executable file has it's +x (execute) stat enabled.  For example `whereis ls` tells me its in `/bin/ls` with manual for it in /usr/share/man/....  A `stat /bin/ls` shows me the stats for `ls`, and `file /bin/ls` tells me the type of executable etc....

Comment: Is vuze available to 16.04?

Comment: Thanks @muru, it is there. Thanks guiverc also, some useful new commands for a newbie like me. Andrew, it seems to be available on 18.04 as well. Running in to new issues now but I'll try to figure it out. This is a crazy new world to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that your installation of vuze on Xenial Xerus 16.04 is problematic. (Possibly you have used the snap packaging system which I confess to cordially disliking!)

Reverse whatever steps you have taken and *remove* your installed copy of vuze using the Ubuntu Software application, then follow the following steps in sequence:

**1. Install some prerequisites:**

Install the following by copying the entire code box and pasting into a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java fonts-dejavu-extra java-common \
java-wrappers libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 \
libbonoboui2-common libcommons-cli-java libgif7 libglade2-0 libgnome-2-0 \
libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 \
libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 \
libgnomevfs2-common libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 liblog4j1.2-java liborbit-2-0 \
libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java \
libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 \
libwebkitgtk-1.0-common openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

**2. Download and install vuze:**

Use the bare Debian files rather than PPA magic, issuing the following 3 commands *one at a time*:

```
wget http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb/ubuntu/pool/apps/a/azureus/azureus_5.7.5.0-1~getdeb1_all.deb
wget http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb/ubuntu/pool/apps/a/azureus/vuze_5.7.5.0-1~getdeb1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

On my system this leaves vuze in a location that is *easy to find*:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ sudo find /usr -iname vuze
[sudo] password for andrew: 
/usr/bin/vuze              <-----------
/usr/share/doc/vuze
andrew@corinth:~$
```

The arrow of course is my own addition :)

**3. Set magnet links to vuze:**

Click on a magnet / torrent link in Firefox and if vuze is not an *immediate* option (competitor would be transmission) you can easily navigate to vuze and select this as *the new default*. See the screenshot below for this seen on my own system:

[image]

This worked *easily* on my Xenial system and hopefully will on yours as well :)

Comment: @themictionary Great news :)